# Changing background colour/button colour in TKinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating the below program, I have tried adding various solutions to change the graphics but I am failing miserably, I would like to change the colour of background and button colours, can someone advice how?

responses will be appreciated -   I am unable to paste code here as it says I have to indent code by 4 spaces which is odd

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. But where is the program? I'm not sure why indenting by four spaces prohibits you from uploading a sample (we don't need the whole thing; just the relevant bits). And when you ask or edit a question, there is a handy button that looks something like this `{}` that will do the indentation for you. You really do have to upload some code to get any sort of response on Stack Overflow.

Comment: paste the code, select all the code, and press the button that looks like `{}` in the edit window toolbar. Also, what does "failing miserably" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: To paste your code into the question simply highlight all of the code and click `Ctrl-k` which will indent the code four spaces. The reason you need to indent the code is so the website can properly display the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, changing the button color. If I have a button called `button_1` I can set the background like this:

```
button_1 = Button(background="blue")
```

The above code would create a blank blue button. You can use most standard colors by their name. E.g, 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black' and many others.

Second, changing the background color of the window. If my main window is named `root` try this to change the background color of the window:

```
root.config(background = "red")
```

Here is a very minimal example using both of those methods to create a red window with a blue button in it.

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.config(background = "red")

button_1 = Button(background = "blue")
button_1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps you out!